# Breaking down percentile data by date using read.table in R

Tags: r, dataframe, data.table

I have the following toy data set:

```
dt <- read.table(text = "
Date                    Model      Color    Value   Samples
1/29/2020 6:51:19 AM    Gold       Blue     0.5     500
1/29/2020 7:57:47 AM    Gold       Red      0.0     449
1/29/2020 3:39:04 PM    Silver     Blue     0.75    1320
1/29/2020 5:04:32 PM    Silver     Blue     1.5     103
1/29/2020 10:32:39 AM   Gold       Red      0.7     891
1/30/2020 1:02:12 AM    Gold       Blue     0.41    18103
1/30/2020 4:30:00 AM    Copper     Blue     0.83    564
1/30/2020 9:09:45 AM    Silver     Pink     1.17    173
1/30/2020 2:19:30 PM    Platinum   Brown    0.43    793
1/30/2020 4:43:32 PM    Platinum   Red      0.71    1763
1/30/2020 7:19:00 PM    Gold       Orange   1.92    503",
                 header = TRUE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

I then take this data.table and generate some percentile data, as follows:

```
qs = dt[Value > 0, .(Samples = sum(Samples),
                     '50th'    = quantile(Value, probs = c(0.50)),
                     '75th'    = quantile(Value, probs = c(0.75)),
                     '90th'    = quantile(Value, probs = c(0.90)), 
                     '99th'    = quantile(Value, probs = c(0.99))),
        by = .(Model, Color)]
setkey(qs, 'Model')
```

Lastly, I output the results to a .csv file:

```
#outputs to csv file

write.csv(qs, file = "outfile.csv")
```

**Question:** how would I write the results so that:

a) the results are broken down **by date** (that is, only taking the date, e.g. 1/30/2020 and 1/31/2020, and not including the times)
b) the dates are written in rows

For example (note: the values below are toy data and not the real computations... just want to show how the "Date" column would be represented):

```
#       Model  Color Samples  50th   99th  99.9th  99.99th Date
# 1:   Copper   Blue     564 0.830 0.8300 0.83000 0.830000 01/29/2020
# 2:     Gold   Blue   18603 0.455 0.4991 0.49991 0.499991 01/29/2020
# 3:     Gold    Red     891 0.700 0.7000 0.70000 0.700000 01/29/2020
# 4:     Gold Orange     503 1.920 1.9200 1.92000 1.920000 01/29/2020
# 5: Platinum  Brown     793 0.430 0.4300 0.43000 0.430000 01/29/2020
# 6: Platinum    Red    1763 0.710 0.7100 0.71000 0.710000 01/29/2020
# 7:   Silver   Blue    1423 1.125 1.4925 1.49925 1.499925 01/29/2020
# 8:   Silver   Pink     173 1.170 1.1700 1.17000 1.170000 01/29/2020
# 9:   Copper   Blue     564 0.830 0.8300 0.83000 0.830000 01/30/2020
#10:     Gold   Blue   18603 0.455 0.4991 0.49991 0.499991 01/30/2020
#11:     Gold    Red     891 0.700 0.7000 0.70000 0.700000 01/30/2020
#12:     Gold Orange     503 1.920 1.9200 1.92000 1.920000 01/30/2020
#13: Platinum  Brown     793 0.430 0.4300 0.43000 0.430000 01/30/2020
#14: Platinum    Red    1763 0.710 0.7100 0.71000 0.710000 01/30/2020
#15:   Silver   Blue    1423 1.125 1.4925 1.49925 1.499925 01/30/2020
#16:   Silver   Pink     173 1.170 1.1700 1.17000 1.170000 01/30/2020
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If we need to create columns in the original dataset, use `:=`

```
library(dplyr)
library(lubridate)
setDT(dt)[Value > 0,  c("Samples", '50th', '75th', '90th', '99th') := 
    c(list(sum(Samples)), as.list(quantile(Value,
      probs = c(0.50, 0.75, 0.90, 0.99)))),
        .(Model, Color, DateNoTime = as.Date(mdy_hms(Date)) )]
dt
#                     Date    Model  Color Value Samples  50th   75th  90th   99th
# 1:  1/29/2020 6:51:19 AM     Gold   Blue  0.50     500 0.500 0.5000 0.500 0.5000
# 2:  1/29/2020 7:57:47 AM     Gold    Red  0.00     449    NA     NA    NA     NA
# 3:  1/29/2020 3:39:04 PM   Silver   Blue  0.75    1423 1.125 1.3125 1.425 1.4925
# 4:  1/29/2020 5:04:32 PM   Silver   Blue  1.50    1423 1.125 1.3125 1.425 1.4925
# 5: 1/29/2020 10:32:39 AM     Gold    Red  0.70     891 0.700 0.7000 0.700 0.7000
# 6:  1/30/2020 1:02:12 AM     Gold   Blue  0.41   18103 0.410 0.4100 0.410 0.4100
# 7:  1/30/2020 4:30:00 AM   Copper   Blue  0.83     564 0.830 0.8300 0.830 0.8300
# 8:  1/30/2020 9:09:45 AM   Silver   Pink  1.17     173 1.170 1.1700 1.170 1.1700
# 9:  1/30/2020 2:19:30 PM Platinum  Brown  0.43     793 0.430 0.4300 0.430 0.4300
#10:  1/30/2020 4:43:32 PM Platinum    Red  0.71    1763 0.710 0.7100 0.710 0.7100
#11:  1/30/2020 7:19:00 PM     Gold Orange  1.92     503 1.920 1.9200 1.920 1.9200
```

This would also fill the rows having `Value <= 0` with `NA` for those new columns.

---

But, if the intention is to have all the rows filled with the summarised values, then do a join and create the 'qs' by including the 'Date' part along in `by`

```
qs <- setDT(dt)[Value > 0, .(Samples = sum(Samples),
                     '50th'    = quantile(Value, probs = c(0.50)),
                     '75th'    = quantile(Value, probs = c(0.75)),
                     '90th'    = quantile(Value, probs = c(0.90)), 
                     '99th'    = quantile(Value, probs = c(0.99))),
        by = .(Model, Color,
          DateNoTime = format(as.Date(mdy_hms(Date)), "%m/%d/%Y") )]



qs[dt, on = .(Model, Color)]
```

---

If we don't want to include the 'Date' in the `by` and only need it in output

```
setDT(dt)[, DateNoTime := as.Date(mdy_hms(Date))
     ][Value > 0,  c("Samples", '50th', '75th', '90th', '99th') := 
    c(list(sum(Samples)), as.list(quantile(Value,
      probs = c(0.50, 0.75, 0.90, 0.99)))),
        .(Model, Color)]
dt
#                     Date    Model  Color Value Samples DateNoTime  50th   75th  90th   99th
# 1:  1/29/2020 6:51:19 AM     Gold   Blue  0.50   18603 2020-01-29 0.455 0.4775 0.491 0.4991
# 2:  1/29/2020 7:57:47 AM     Gold    Red  0.00     449 2020-01-29    NA     NA    NA     NA
# 3:  1/29/2020 3:39:04 PM   Silver   Blue  0.75    1423 2020-01-29 1.125 1.3125 1.425 1.4925
# 4:  1/29/2020 5:04:32 PM   Silver   Blue  1.50    1423 2020-01-29 1.125 1.3125 1.425 1.4925
# 5: 1/29/2020 10:32:39 AM     Gold    Red  0.70     891 2020-01-29 0.700 0.7000 0.700 0.7000
# 6:  1/30/2020 1:02:12 AM     Gold   Blue  0.41   18603 2020-01-30 0.455 0.4775 0.491 0.4991
# 7:  1/30/2020 4:30:00 AM   Copper   Blue  0.83     564 2020-01-30 0.830 0.8300 0.830 0.8300
# 8:  1/30/2020 9:09:45 AM   Silver   Pink  1.17     173 2020-01-30 1.170 1.1700 1.170 1.1700
# 9:  1/30/2020 2:19:30 PM Platinum  Brown  0.43     793 2020-01-30 0.430 0.4300 0.430 0.4300
#10:  1/30/2020 4:43:32 PM Platinum    Red  0.71    1763 2020-01-30 0.710 0.7100 0.710 0.7100
#11:  1/30/2020 7:19:00 PM     Gold Orange  1.92     503 2020-01-30 1.920 1.9200 1.920 1.9200
```

#### data

```
dt <- structure(list(Date = c("1/29/2020 6:51:19 AM", "1/29/2020 7:57:47 AM", 
"1/29/2020 3:39:04 PM", "1/29/2020 5:04:32 PM", "1/29/2020 10:32:39 AM", 
"1/30/2020 1:02:12 AM", "1/30/2020 4:30:00 AM", "1/30/2020 9:09:45 AM", 
"1/30/2020 2:19:30 PM", "1/30/2020 4:43:32 PM", "1/30/2020 7:19:00 PM"
), Model = c("Gold", "Gold", "Silver", "Silver", "Gold", "Gold", 
"Copper", "Silver", "Platinum", "Platinum", "Gold"), Color = c("Blue", 
"Red", "Blue", "Blue", "Red", "Blue", "Blue", "Pink", "Brown", 
"Red", "Orange"), Value = c(0.5, 0, 0.75, 1.5, 0.7, 0.41, 0.83, 
1.17, 0.43, 0.71, 1.92), Samples = c(500L, 449L, 1320L, 103L, 
891L, 18103L, 564L, 173L, 793L, 1763L, 503L)), 
class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-11L))
```

Comment: Referring to the toy data set, the intention is to compute the percentile data on only the two dates (not including the numerous times over those two dates).

Comment: @equanimity I updated the post.  Please check if this solvess the issue

Comment: when I create the "qs" data table and use your code, I see the following error:  "Error in `[.data.table`(qs, dt, on = .(Model, Color)) : 
  Column(s) [Model,Color] not found in x"

Comment: @equanimity I am assuming that `qs` is data.table

Comment: @equanimity I updated with the data I used.  There were some typos in my post.   Sorry. It is now working for me

Comment: the code that you posted returns errors.  I was hoping that someone would be able to suggest a slight modification to my existing code (rather than a complete rewrite).

Comment: @equanimity As I mentioned, I am not getting any errors with the data showed in the post

Comment: that was a mistake on my part.  I intended to check your response as the answer (which I've done).  I've also upvoted :).